# I don't know how to link a compiler to an IDE

Tags: apt, c++

I AM NOT BEING DUMB HERE!

Maybe I kind of am, but right now the Raspberry Pi IDE QTCreator does not come with a compiler.

Okay, now I'm a bit confused. Not really.

Upon discovering that QTCreator did not come with a compiler, I immediately lost myself to Youtube and found a way to install the compiler G++. Worked.

Now here comes the problem. When adding a compiler to be used by QTCreator, it required me to enter the file path of the compiler I wanted to link. Thing is, how do you like a file that was installed with `sudo apt-get`? Last time I checked, any files installed with `sudo apt-get` don't appear in your desktop. So what is the file path for the compiler file installed with `apt-get`?

Where is it even located?

QTCreator installed with both `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` and `sudo apt-get install qtcreator`.

Run with `qtcreator`

Compiler G++ was installed with `sudo apt-get install gcc`

And the standard C++ libraries installed with `apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-dev`

Yes, I am trying to program in C++.

Another thing. Do I need the compiler at all? Or does QTCreator save C++ files with the apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-de

Yes, I am coding (or trying to) in C++.

Do I even need the compiler? Or does QTCreator automatically save is as a *cpp* file?

:) Thanks.

Comment: You are not being dumb. You are just standing at the very beginning and try to find your way, beginning from "where am a right now?" and "where do I need to go from here?". Better get used to this feeling of trying to understand seemingly basic stuff, this is something that will **inevitably** repeat itself when you are breaking new ground. Trust me I'm programming since 30 years, and as long I'm excited to learn new stuff (I hope) it won't bring me down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ compiler is called **g++**. Don't try to use *gcc* , it will not work properly.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential
```

To list package contents , use

```
dpkg -L packagename
```

You should always try to use apt to install software on Raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Synaptic is a graphical tool. It should make it easier for you to manage and search packages on Raspbian where plain apt is too confusing.

Answer (score -1):

[QT-Creator](https://www.qt.io/ide/) is your integrated development environment (IDE). It integrates access to all kind of usfull tools, makes it easy to get a good overview of your project and switch from one tool to another easily.

The downside is that you now have that much more stuff in front of you to learn and might have trouble keep focused to get anything done.

Generally speaking you don't need a IDE to write a program. To write a C++ program a good text-editor and the compiler itself will do.

[apt-get](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/apt-get.htm) and is a front-end to install [dpkg](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dpkg.htm)-files. You will use them to install your tools. You don't need to build your own dpkg-files to create a application. Compiling your C++ program is enough to create a working application.